# Hourglass sum in 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

We are given a (6*6) 2D array of which we have to find largest sum of a hourglass in it.
For example, if we create an hourglass using the number 1 within an array full of zeros, it may look like this:

[image]

The sum of an hourglass is the sum of all the numbers within it. The sum for the hourglasses above are 7, 4, and 2, respectively.

[image]

I had written a code for it as follows.It is basically a competitive programming question and as I am new to the field,I have written the code with a very bad compplexity..perhaps so much that the program could not produce the desired output within the stipulated period of time.Below is my code:

```
    int main(){
    vector< vector<int> > arr(6,vector<int>(6));
    for(int arr_i = 0;arr_i < 6;arr_i++)
    {
      for(int arr_j = 0;arr_j < 6;arr_j++)
       {
        cin >> arr[arr_i][arr_j];
       }
    } //numbers input

    int temp; //temporary sum storing variable
    int sum=INT_MIN; //largest sum storing variable
    for(int i=0;i+2<6;i++) //check if at least3 exist at bottom
     { 
       int c=0; //starting point of traversing column wise for row

       while(c+2<6) //three columns exist ahead from index
        {  
          int f=0; //test case variable
          while(f!=1)  
          { //if array does not meet requirements,no need of more execution  

            for(int j=c;j<=j+2;j++)
             { //1st and 3rd row middle element is 0 and 2nd row is non 0.
               //condition for hourglass stucture                    
             if((j-c)%2==0 && arr[i+1][j]==0||((j-c)%2==1 && arr[i+1][j]!=0)
             //storing 3 dimensional subarray sum column wise               
             temp+=arr[i][j]+arr[i+1][j]+arr[i+2][j]; //sum storage 
             else
             f=1; //end traversing further on failure


              if(sum<temp)
              sum=temp;

              f=1;//exit condition
              }//whiel loop of test variable 

             temp=0; //reset for next subarray execution
             c++; /*begin traversal from one index greater column wise till 
                    condition*/
              }// while loop of c
        } 
      }       

          cout<<sum;

         return 0;
    }
```

This is my implementation of the code which failed to process in the time interval.Please suggest a better solution considering the time complexity and feel free to point out any mistakes from my side in understanding the problem.The question is from Hackerrank.
Here is the link if you need it anyways:
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/2d-array

Comment: Surprising,the image links aren't working.Please refer to the link at the bottom to understand the full problem.

Comment: you might have better luck posting this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ , if your code is already working.

Comment: did you test it for some input?

Comment: Looping over a 6x6 array should not take very long - I suspect you have an infinite loop somewhere in your code. The `while`s are particularly suspicious - you should need at most two `for`s for a simple algorithm.

Comment: What does it mean `//1st and 3rd row middle element is 0 and 2nd row is non 0.` ?

Comment: If you look at an hour glass structure,it  usually has three numbers in uppermost and lowermost row and one element in the middle to represent its neck.0 indicates that field at  that cell  is purposely left blank as you cannot allot null values in arrays.

Comment: As we are traversing column wise,we see cells through a row perspective.Seing through in that case,the first and third row middle elements should have no cell,so as to satisfy the neck element condition,.i.e.,cells next to it on either side should be left blank.

Comment: It looks like usual 2d convolution. (For instance https://www.thanassis.space/straylight.html) .     Google it, it has a lot of standard good optimized ready to use solutions. Kernel will look like hourglass, consisting of ones. Also take a look at separable convolution.

Comment: Seems almost impossible to achieve a time complexity lower than O(n^2)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution for your problem is:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>

int main() {
    int m[6][6];

    // Read 2D Matrix-Array
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; ++j) {
            std:: cin >> m[i][j];
        }
    }

    // Compute the sum of hourglasses
    long temp_sum = 0, MaxSum = LONG_MIN;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; ++j) {
            if (j + 2 < 6 && i + 2 < 6) {
                temp_sum = m[i][j] + m[i][j + 1] + m[i][j + 2] + m[i + 1][j + 1] + m[i + 2][j] + m[i + 2][j + 1] + m[i + 2][j + 2];
                if (temp_sum >= MaxSum) {
                    MaxSum = temp_sum;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "Max Sum: %ld\n", MaxSum);

    return 0;
}
```

The algorithm is simple, it sums all the Hourglasses starting of the upper left corner and the last 2 columns and 2 rows are not processed because it can not form hourglasses.

Comment: This indeed is a better and more concise way of approaching the problem.Thank you for your time and efforts.

Comment: Sure,but I have added a slight modification to the code to make it work in all possible test cases.Please go through to it once.

Comment: why we should have extra if condition, it can be solved without it if we loop from 1 to 5 and adjust the index accordingly

Comment: @mohit from 0 to 4, no?

Answer (score 8):

The above code is almost correct, but it does not work for a negative array elements.We should not take max sum as 0 as negative numbers array might not reach their max sum total >=0. In this case, initializing max sum to `INT_MIN` is a better option.

Comment: Can you please explain your answer?

Answer (score 4):

I have solved in Python 3.0 and passed all test cases in HackerRank:
**Idea:** in just 3 simple steps:

1. To extract all 16 3X3 in 6X6 matrix. Get each sub-matrix sum Find
   the max of all sub-matrix sum

I have initialized max as -1000 for negative values you can also initialize it with Minimum_Integer value

```
 # Complete the hourglassSum function below.
    def hourglassSum(arr):
        max = -1000
        s= []
        sub_array = []
        for m in range(4)://Move vertically down the rows like(012,123,234,345 and taking 3 values horizontally)
            for col in range(4):
                for row in range(3):
                    sub_array.append(arr[row+m][col:col+3])
                    s = sub_array//Extracting all 16 3X3 matrices
                hour_sum = sum_list(s[0])+s[1][1]+sum_list(s[2])//Mask array for hour_glass index[[1,1,1],[0,1,1],[1,1,1]]
                if (max<hour_sum):
                    max = hour_sum
                sub_array = []
        return max

    def sum_list(list1):
        total = 0
        for ele in range(0, len(list1)):
            total = total + list1[ele]
        return total
```

"""
**Extra: Try replacing this in your Spyder for lesser lines of code 
Instead of**

**Existing: without numpy**

```
hour_sum = sum_list(s[0])+s[1][1]+sum_list(s[2])//Mask array for hour_glass index[[1,1,1],[0,1,1],[1,1,1]]
        if (max<hour_sum):
           max = hour_sum
```

**With numpy:**

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma
    hour_glass = ma.array(sub_array, mask=mask)
            sum = hour_glass.data.sum()
```

"""

Answer (score 3):

Swift 4 version:

```
func hourglassSum(arr matrix: [[Int]]) -> Int {
      let h = matrix.count
      if h < 3 {
         return 0
      }
      let w = matrix[0].count
      if w < 3 {
         return 0
      }
      var maxSum: Int?

      for i in 0 ..< h - 2 {
         for j in 0 ..< w - 2 {
            // Considering matrix[i][j] as top left cell of hour glass.
            let sum = matrix[i][j] + matrix[i][j+1] + matrix[i][j+2]
               + matrix[i+1][j+1]
               + matrix[i+2][j] + matrix[i+2][j+1] + matrix[i+2][j+2]
            // If previous sum is less then current sum then update new sum in maxSum
            if let maxValue = maxSum {
               maxSum = max(maxValue, sum)
            } else {
               maxSum = sum
            }
         }
      }
      return maxSum ?? 0
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**#JavaScript(Nodejs)**

```
function hourglassSum(arr) {
    // Write your code here
    let count = -63;

  for(let i = 0; i <= 3; i++){
    for(let j = 0; j <= 3; j++){
      let sum = arr[i][j] + arr[i][j+1] + arr[i][j+2] + arr[i+1][j+1] 
      + arr[i+2][j] + arr[i+2][j+1] + arr[i+2][j+2]

      if(sum > count){
        count = sum
      }
    }
  }
  return count;

}
```

Comment: How did you come up with the `-63` value for `count`?

Answer (score 2):

Here is python implementation of this algorithm.

```
arr = []

for _ in xrange(6):
    arr.append(map(int, raw_input().rstrip().split()))

maxSum = -99999999
for row in range(len(arr)):
    tempSum = 0
    for col in range(len(arr[row])):
        if col+2 >= len(arr[row]) or row+2 >= len(arr[col]):
            continue
        tempSum = arr[row][col] + arr[row][col+1] + arr[row][col+2] + arr[row+1][col+1] + arr[row+2][col] + arr[row+2][col+1] + arr[row+2][col+2]
        if maxSum < tempSum:
            maxSum = tempSum
print(maxSum)
```

Answer (score 2):

Basic solution for java;

```
  static int hourglassSum(int[][] arr) {
        
        int sum = 0;
        
        for(int i = 2; i<6; i++){
            for(int j = 2; j<6; j++){
                
                int up = arr[i-2][j-2] + arr[i-2][j-1] + arr[i-2][j];
                int mid = arr[i-1][j-1];
                int down = arr[i][j-2] + arr[i][j-1] + arr[i][j];
                
                if(up+mid+down > sum){
                     sum = up+mid+down;
                }
            }    
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Python clean and fast solution

```
def hourglassSum(arr):
    arr_sum = -5000
    tmp_sum = 0
    
    for i in range(0, 6-2):
        for j in range (0, 6-2):
            tmp_sum = arr[i][j] + arr[i][j+1] + arr[i][j+2] + \
                             + arr[i+1][j+1]  + \
                    arr[i+2][j] + arr[i+2][j+1] + arr[i+2][j+2]
      
            if arr_sum < tmp_sum:
                arr_sum = tmp_sum
    
    return arr_sum
```

Answer (score 1):

Just avoided four for loop iterations

```
 int main()
{
 int arr[6][6],max=-1,sum;
for(int arr_i = 0; arr_i < 6; arr_i++){
   for(int arr_j = 0; arr_j < 6; arr_j++){

      scanf("%d",&arr[arr_i][arr_j]);
       if(arr[arr_i][arr_j]<-9||arr[arr_i][arr_j]>9)
           exit(0);
   }
}
 for(int arr_i = 0; arr_i <4; arr_i++)
 {
     sum=0;
   for(int arr_j = 0; arr_j < 4; arr_j++){
        sum=arr[arr_i][arr_j]+arr[arr_i][arr_j+1]+arr[arr_i][arr_j+2]+arr[arr_i+1][arr_j+1]+arr[arr_i+2][arr_j]+arr[arr_i+2][arr_j+1]+arr[arr_i+2][arr_j+2];
       if(sum>max)
        max=sum;


   }
}
printf("%d",max);
return 0;
```

}

Comment: What are you attempting to achieve here? If you think you're providing a useful answer then some explanation might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
 int main(){
    vector< vector<int> > arr(6,vector<int>(6));
    for(int arr_i = 0;arr_i < 6;arr_i++){
       for(int arr_j = 0;arr_j < 6;arr_j++){
          cin >> arr[arr_i][arr_j];
       }
    }

    int sum=-100, temp;
    for(int arr_i = 0;arr_i < 4;arr_i++){
       for(int arr_j = 0;arr_j < 4;arr_j++){
           temp=(arr[arr_i][arr_j]+arr[arr_i][arr_j+1]+arr[arr_i][arr_j+2]+arr[arr_i+1][arr_j+1]+arr[arr_i+2][arr_j]+arr[arr_i+2][arr_j+1]+arr[arr_i+2][arr_j+2]);
           if(temp>sum)
               sum=temp;
       }
    }
    cout << sum;    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation with your answers. [answer]

Answer (score 1):

```
def hourglassSum(arr)
maxHourGlass = -82
counter = 0
for i in 1..4
    for j in 1..4
        acc = arr[i][j]
        counter= counter +1
        for x in -1..1
            acc = acc + arr[i-1][j+x] + arr[i+1][j+x]
        end
        maxHourGlass = acc if acc > maxHourGlass
    end
end
maxHourGlass
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This is written in C++14 and passes all nine test cases. I think someone could improve it to use more C++14 features.

```
int hourglassSum(vector<vector<int>> arr)
{
    if(arr.size() < 3 || arr[0].size() < 3 )
        return -1;

    int rowSize = arr[0].size();
    int sum = -9 * 6; // smallest negative sum possible;

    for( int i = 1; i < arr.size()-1; i++ )
    {
        int tmp_sum = 0;

        for( int j = 1; j < rowSize-1; j++ )
        {
            tmp_sum  = (arr[i - 1][j - 1] + arr[i - 1][j] + arr[i - 1][j + 1] );
            tmp_sum += (arr[i    ][j    ]);
            tmp_sum += (arr[i + 1][j - 1] + arr[i + 1][j] + arr[i + 1][j + 1]);

            sum = max(tmp_sum, sum);
        }
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Solution {

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        int[][] arr = new int[6][];

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            arr[i] = Array.ConvertAll(Console.ReadLine().Split(' '), arrTemp => Convert.ToInt32(arrTemp));
        }
        int[] sum=new int[16];
        int j;
        int count=0;
        for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<4;j++)
        {
            if(count<16)
            {
           sum[count]=arr[i][j]+arr[i][j+1]+arr[i][j+2]+arr[i+1][j+1]+arr[i+2][j]+arr[i+2][j+1]+arr[i+2][j+2];
           count++;
            }
        }

        }
        int max=sum.Max();
        Console.WriteLine(max);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Largest (maximum) hourglass sum found in the array will be -63 as the element cannot be greater than -9 i.e. -9*7 = -63**

C#

```
int max_hourglass_sum = -63;
for (int i = 0; i <arr.Length-2; i++) { //row
    for (int j = 0 ; j<arr.Length-2; j++) { //column
        int current_hourglass_sum = arr[i][j] + arr[i][j+1] + arr[i][j+2]  //1st row
            + arr[i+1][j+1] //2nd row
            + arr[i+2][j] + arr[i+2][j+1] + arr[i+2][j+2] ;//3rd row
        max_hourglass_sum = Math.Max(max_hourglass_sum , current_hourglass_sum); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
static int hourglassSum(int[][] arr) {
    int result = int.MinValue;
    int rowLength = arr.GetLength(0);
    int colLength = arr.Length;
    
   for (int i = 0; i < rowLength - 2; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j< colLength - 2; j++)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            sum = arr[i][j] + arr[i][j+1] + arr[i][j+2]+ arr[i+1][j+1]
                + arr[i+2][j] + arr[i+2][j+1] + arr[i+2][j+2];
            result = Math.Max(result,sum);
        }
    } 
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function hourglassSum(arr) {
    const hourGlass = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (let x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
            let hourGlassSumValue = arr[i][x] + arr[i][x + 1] + arr[i][x + 2] + arr[i + 1][x + 1] + arr[i + 2]enter code here[x] + arr[i + 2][x + 1] + arr[i + 2][x + 2];
            hourGlass.push(hourGlassSumValue);
        }
    }
    return Math.max(...hourGlass);
}
console.log(hourglassSum(cars));
```