# Can not get precise results for the hourglass algorithm

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, array-algorithms

Here is the link for definition of the hourglass problem:
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-2d-arrays

I wrote the following program:

```
package day11;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String ... args){

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int[][] arr = new int[6][6];

        int maxHourGlassValue = 0;
        int temp = 0;
        int currMax = 0;

        int k = 0, l = 0;

        for(int i = 0 ; i < 6 ; i++){
            for(int j = 0 ; j < 6 ; j++){
                arr[i][j] = scan.nextInt();
            }
        }

        for(int i = 1 ; i < 5 ; i++){
            for(int j = 1 ; j < 5 ; j++){
                    if(maxHourGlassValue < currMax){
                    maxHourGlassValue = currMax;
                }
            }


        }

        System.out.println(maxHourGlassValue);

    }

}
```

I could only run 6 out of 8 given test cases. What could possibly go wrong ????

Comment: *What could possibly go wrong?*  Lots.  People code errors all the time.  That's why debugging is an entire field of academic study.

Comment: You haven't written any logic so far. It's not even running for sample test case then how it'll run for 6 out of 8. Anyway I have answered a complete tested code for your hourglass problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, i did not write that code, i just copy it and modified it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38019861/hourglass-sum-in-2d-array)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test {

    public static void main(String ... args){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int size = 6;
        int[][]  m = new int[size][size];

      //numbers input
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
        {
          for(int j=0; j<size; j++)
           {
            m[i][j] = scan.nextInt();
           }
        } 

        int temp = 0, MaxSum = -99999;

        for (int i=0; i<size; ++i) {
            for (int j=0; j<size; ++j) {
                if (j+2 < size && i+2 < size) {
                    temp = m[i][j] + m[i][j+1] + m[i][j+2] + m[i+1][j+1] + m[i+2][j] + m[i+2][j+1] + m[i+2][j+2];
                    if (temp >= MaxSum) {
                        MaxSum = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
        }   
        System.out.println(MaxSum);

    }

}
```

Comment: It would be better if you could provide some description as well. You can place `temp > MaxSum` condition instead of  `temp >= MaxSum` in ` if ` inside `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code which will run successfully for all the test cases of [hourglass problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-2d-arrays/problem).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        int[][] arr = new int[6][6];

        int maxHourGlassValue = -63;//Assigning (-9*7=)-63 which is the minimum possible value of "hourglass sum".

        //Reading inputs.
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
                arr[i][j] = scan.nextInt();
            }
        }

        //Logic.
        /**
         * Index of both i and j will run from 1 to 4 (one less than n-1 where n = 6)
         * So for each i and j iteration calculating the sum of hourglass.
         */
        int iHGValueTemp = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < 5; j++) {
                iHGValueTemp = arr[i][j] + /*Main element*/
                        arr[i - 1][j - 1] + arr[i - 1][j] + arr[i - 1][j + 1]+ /*Top three elements of main element.*/
                        arr[i + 1][j - 1] + arr[i + 1][j] + arr[i + 1][j + 1]; /*Bottom three elements of main element.*/
                if (iHGValueTemp > maxHourGlassValue) {
                    maxHourGlassValue = iHGValueTemp;
                }
            }

        }

        //Output.
        System.out.println(maxHourGlassValue);
    }
}
```

I have written description within code in the comments only. Please refer to that and discuss with me if any doubt.