# Is const keyword just for the compiler?

Tags: c, arrays, memory, constants

I got struck with an issue while trying to solve the simple 2D- array Hourglass challenge: 
Someone posted this challenge in detail here [Hourglass sum in 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38019861/hourglass-sum-in-2d-array)

Now, coming to my code, I just tried to solve it as below (I know my method is very inefficient :) )

```
main()
{

    int i, j;
    int A[6][6] = { {1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 2, 4, 4, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 1, 2, 4, 0 }
    };
    const int const index[] = { 0, 1, 2, 7, 12, 13, 14 };

    int res[7] = { 0 }, k = 0, l = 0;
    int * ptr = &(A[0][0]);

    for (i = 0; i < 21; i++)
    {
        //ptr = &(A[i][0]);
        for (j = 0; j < 7; j++)
        {
            res[k] += *((ptr + index[j]));
        }
        if (k >0 && res[k] > res[k - 1])
        {
            l = res[k];
        }
        k++;
        ptr++;
        printf("%X,", ptr);
    }

    printf("\n%d", l);

}
```

But the strange issue I came across is that, while this code reaches the point where (I think its A[1,4]), the value of my index[] array itself is getting modified so that index values from 0 - 6 gets assigned with some garbage values!., eventually the program crashes, since this garbage value gets added to the base pointer which results in access violation.
While, I can understand any possible issues with my array manipulation logic, I couldn't understand why the constant index array is getting corrupted .

Comment: Why not access array `A` like `A[index[j]/6][index[j]%6]` ?

Comment: Yes, it does absolutely nothing to solve UB.  Like the kind you get by letting the `k` variable get larger than 6.  Which will index `res` out of bounds, destroying the content of adjacent variables.   Use `assert` to test invariants.

Comment: You increment `k` each time in your loop... You might try to make `index` `static` and `const` but then you will just kill another poor variable on your stack when `k` gets out of bounds.

Comment: `const` is not enforced by the compiler, but a guaranmtee **you** give to the compiler. If you break it, for some reason, it is your fault.