# Why python sum() function doesn't work in this case?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, sum

The prompt for the question is linked here:[Hourglass sum in 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38019861/hourglass-sum-in-2d-array)

I have written 2 different codes that are supposed to output the same thing.

Code1

```py
def hourglassSum(arr):
    total = []
    for i in range(0, 4):
        for j in range(0, 4):
            total.append(arr[i][j] + arr[i][j+1] + arr[i][j+2] + arr[i+1][j+1] + arr[i+2][j]+ arr[i+2][j+1]+ arr[i+2][j+2])
    return max(total)
```

Code2

```py
def hourglassSum(arr):
    total = []
    for i in range(0, 4):
        for j in range(0, 4):
            total.append(sum(arr[i][j:j+2]) + arr[i+1][j+1] + sum(arr[i+2][j:j+2]))
    return max(total)
```

The 2nd code outputs a different value. Can anyone tell me what went wrong?

Comment: What have you thought of?

Comment: @Gulzar I don't know. As far as I know, they're supposed to return the same value.

Comment: Just eye-balling it, I'd guess that you are not including the last index that you want.

Comment: Would say you need `[j:j+3]` rather than `[j:j+2]` (i.e. slice is not inclusive of the right end point).

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to include the not-included index. A slice has the format of `start:end` where the `end` integer is *not* included. So you have to do a +1 when converting from indices to a slice.

```py
def hourglassSum1(arr):
    total = []
    for i in range(0, 4):
        for j in range(0, 4):
            total.append(arr[i][j] + arr[i][j+1] + arr[i][j+2] + arr[i+1][j+1] + arr[i+2][j]+ arr[i+2][j+1]+ arr[i+2][j+2])
    return max(total)

def hourglassSum2(arr):
    total = []
    for i in range(0, 4):
        for j in range(0, 4):
            # Use +3
            total.append(sum(arr[i][j:j+3]) + arr[i+1][j+1] + sum(arr[i+2][j:j+3]))
    return max(total)


l = [[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

assert hourglassSum1(l) == hourglassSum2(l)
```

Answer (score 2):

Let `arr = [[1, 2, 3]]` for this example.

`sum(arr[0][0:2]) = 3` because we are summing 1 and 2.

`sum(arr[0][0:3]) = 6` because we are summing 1, 2 and 3.

So the answer to your question is that `[j:j+2]` does not include `j+2`. You want to use `[j:j+3]`